# How to put geom_label in a geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am doing this graph with this code

```
ggplot(c_clinicos) +
 aes(x = Condición, fill = Estado, weight = Conteo) +
 geom_bar() +
 scale_fill_manual(values = list(
 Ausente = "#FF1100", Presente = "#538FF6")) +
  labs(x = "Condición clínica", y = "Nº Personas. ", 
       title = "Distribución de la presencia por enfermedad", subtitle = "Muestra de 810 pacientes", fill = "Estado:")  +
 coord_flip() +
 theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

I want to get a little square for each bar (blue and red) that tells me how many people there is and a %. I have been trying to use geom_label but I couldn't make that work.

I am using this data:

```
structure(list(Condición = c("Cianosis Aguda", "Cianosis Aguda", 
"Gassping", "Gassping", "FR mayor de 40 o menor de 6 rpm", "FR mayor de 40 o menor de 6 rpm", 
"Oliguria que no responde a volumen y uso de diuréticos", "Oliguria que no responde a volumen y uso de diuréticos", 
"Transtornos de la coagulación", "Transtornos de la coagulación", 
"Pérdida de la conciencia mayor de 12 horas", "Pérdida de la conciencia mayor de 12 horas", 
"Pérdida de la conciencia y ausencia de pulso y latidos cardíacos.", 
"Pérdida de la conciencia y ausencia de pulso y latidos cardíacos.", 
"Stroke", "Stroke", "Parálisis total o convulsiones incontrolables", 
"Parálisis total o convulsiones incontrolables", "Ictericia más preeclampsia", 
"Ictericia más preeclampsia"), Estado = c("Presente", "Ausente", 
"Presente", "Ausente", "Presente", "Ausente", "Presente", "Ausente", 
"Presente", "Ausente", "Presente", "Ausente", "Presente", "Ausente", 
"Presente", "Ausente", "Presente", "Ausente", "Presente", "Ausente"
), Conteo = c(13, 797, 0, 810, 520, 290, 314, 496, 150, 659, 
1, 809, 1, 809, 9, 801, 49, 761, 114, 696)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate the labels that we want to display and use it in `geom_label`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

c_clinicos %>%
  group_by(Condición) %>%
  mutate(label = sprintf('%d \n(%.2f %%)', Conteo, prop.table(Conteo) * 100), 
         label = replace(label, Conteo == 0, '')) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Condición, fill = Estado, y = Conteo, label = label) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = list(
    Ausente = "#FF1100", Presente = "#538FF6")) +
  labs(x = "Condición clínica", y = "Nº Personas. ", 
       title = "Distribución de la presencia por enfermedad", 
       subtitle = "Muestra de 810 pacientes", fill = "Estado:")  +
  geom_label(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), color = 'white') + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Just one small question, how can I make it two lines like: "N (enter) %". And to not generate the blue one if it's 0 ppl